# MVar tryPut returns true and isEmpty also returns true

Tags: scala, concurrency, scala-cats, side-effects

I wrote simple callback(handler) function which i pass to async api and i want to wait for  result:

```
object Handlers {

  val logger: Logger = Logger("Handlers")
  implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] =
  IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.Implicits.global)

  class DefaultHandler[A] {

  val response: IO[MVar[IO, A]] = MVar.empty[IO, A]

  def onResult(obj: Any): Unit = {
    obj match {
      case obj: A =>
        println(response.flatMap(_.tryPut(obj)).unsafeRunSync())
        println(response.flatMap(_.isEmpty).unsafeRunSync())
      case _ => logger.error("Wrong expected type")
    }
  }

  def getResponse: A = {
    response.flatMap(_.take).unsafeRunSync()
  }
}
```

But for some reason both tryPut and isEmpty(when i'd manually call onResult method) returns true, therefore when i calling getResponse it sleeps forever.
This is the my test:

```
class HandlersTest extends FunSuite {
    test("DefaultHandler.test") {
    val handler = new DefaultHandler[Int]
    handler.onResult(3)
    val response = handler.getResponse
    assert(response != 0)
    }
  }
```

Can somebody explain why tryPut returns true, but nothing puts. And what is the right way to use Mvar/channels in scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IO[X]` means that you have the recipe to create some **X**.  So on your example, yuo are putting in one **MVar** and then asking in another.

Here is how I would do it.

```
object Handlers {
  trait DefaultHandler[A] {
    def onResult(obj: Any): IO[Unit]

    def getResponse: IO[A]
  }

  object DefaultHandler {
    def apply[A : ClassTag]: IO[DefaultHandler[A]] = 
      MVar.empty[IO, A].map { response =>
        new DefaultHandler[A] {
          override def onResult(obj: Any): IO[Unit] = obj match {
              case obj: A =>
                for {
                  r1 <- response.tryPut(obj)
                  _  <- IO(println(r1))
                  r2 <- response.isEmpty
                  _  <- IO(println(r2))
                } yield ()

              case _ =>
                IO(logger.error("Wrong expected type"))
            }

          override def getResponse: IO[A] =
            response.take
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe i'm doing something wrong, but it's seems to deadlock anyway (https://scastie.scala-lang.org/r6WIR1rUTpiv6MH1L4d0XA)

Comment: upd: my test code was wrong, answer below has fixed it

Answer (score 2):

The "unsafe" is sort of a hint, but every time you call `unsafeRunSync`, you should basically think of it as an entire new universe. Before you make the call, you can only describe instructions for what will happen, you can't actually change anything. During the call is when all the changes occur. Once the call completes, that universe is destroyed, and you can read the result but no longer change anything. What happens in one `unsafeRunSync` universe doesn't affect another.

You need to call it *exactly once* in your test code. That means your test code needs to look something like:

```
val test = for {
  handler  <- TestHandler.DefaultHandler[Int]
  _        <- handler.onResult(3)
  response <- handler.getResponse
} yield response
assert test.unsafeRunSync() == 3
```

Note this doesn't really buy you much over just using the `MVar` directly. I think you're trying to mix side effects inside `IO` and outside it, but that doesn't work. All the side effects need to be inside.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answered really helped me understand why my code is't working and how IO works, but I did't quite get how am i mixing side effects inside IO and outside. Could you please explain a bit more about that?

Comment: Anytime you try to use a result you get from running `unsafeRunSync`, such as when you were calling `onResult` on the `handler` you received, that's running outside of `IO`.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt Thanks for looking into this, my weekend was a little bit bussy, I was about to check what was OP's problem, but it seems you already fixed it! :D - Jut to make sure, this correction of the test is the one on the ScalaFiddle that OP posted with my code, right?

Comment: Yes @Luis, I was responding to that ScalaFiddle. You got the OP on the right path, but then he moved the extra unsafeRunSync's into the test instead.

Comment: @Luis, KarlBielefeldt, thank you guys a lot for helping me understand. To elaborate all of this: 1) it's bad to mix side effects inside and outside IO(e.g. working with result from running unsafeRunSync)(but why?). 2) My solution with MVar seems out of place here. What would you recommend to use in this situation, maybe get Future from handler?(method onResult should return nothing because handler extends library class) (this is src of my pet project: https://github.com/ibanezn04/GreatNews/blob/public-master/src/main/scala/main/tdapi/Handlers.scala)

Comment: @ibanezn04 The idea of an **effect system** is to keep track of all your effects. You shouldn't call any of the unsafe functions except on the end of the world. And if you use `IOApp` then you would never need to call any of those. Also, for your use case maybe one of the **Async** helpers would do the trick? I would recommend you to open a new question explaining in detail your problem and provide all the code necessary to test the solution. But before that, make sure to read all the cats-effect documentation and some blogs & talks about IO so you get an idea of how it works.